# How to test asp.net webapi using soapui

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

How to test the MVC 4's ASP.net WebAPI using SoapUI application.?

Comment: I guess "how to test Web API using Fiddler" would have been more appropriate. You don't have a WSDL for Web API which SOAP UI reads to provide you testing environment.

Comment: @helloworld - according to the options available in SOAP UI it looks like it can use plain REST services as well, so that statement doesn't look like it holds up.

Comment: @PHeiberg Yeah! My bad.. http://www.soapui.org/REST-Testing/getting-started.html